# How to use the change function for input types efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tracking the input changes like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').change(function () {
        alert("Key pressed");
    });
    $('textarea').change(function () {
        alert("Key pressed");
    });
    $('input:radio').change(function() {
       alert("Key pressed");
    });
    $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
       alert("Key pressed");
    });
 });
```

Is it possible to re-factor the above code so that I don't need call each element separately?

Comment: If you are using $('input').change then no need to write for radio or checkbox. it will take all the control of input type.

Comment: add same class to those different input types. and use that class in jquery for event.
e.g.
 $(document).on('change', .'common_class', function () {
    alert("Key pressed");
});

Comment: @captainsac i guess you meant `$(':input')` instead

Comment: @  A. Wolff : you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiselectors to refactor your code `:input` it select all input elements

```
$(':input').on('change', function () {
    alert("Key pressed");
});
```

Comment: @Tushar -  `:input` it is Select all input elements:

Comment: `:input` includes `textarea` too :)

Comment: Beware, the alert "Key pressed" is quite unrelevant,  because the `change` event is fired when element is blurred

Comment: @A.Wolff - what we do in the context . can i change the event to keypress

Comment: @JqueryKing On modern browser, your best bet is using `$(':input').on('input', handler);`  if you want to handle all kind of 'change' https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput

Answer (score 4):

jQuery uses the Sizzle selector engine which follows the same rules as CSS. With that in mind, you can separate selectors using `,`. Try this:

```
$('input, textarea').change(function() {
   alert("Key pressed");
});
```

Alternatively you can apply a common class to all those elements and select that instead.

Note that your `:radio` and `:checkbox` selectors are redundant as you select the `input` element anyway. Also note that the `change` event doesn't fire until the element value changed *and* it loses focus. If you want to actually fire an event when a keypress occurs, use `keypress` or `keydown` depending on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 3):

To capture `keypress` event on all inputs you don't have to mention `:checkbox` and `:radio` as they are included in `input`:

```
$('input, textarea').on('change', function () {
    alert("Key pressed");
});
```

You can even use `keypress`/`keyup`/`keydown` events instead of `change`.

> Selects the combined results of all the specified selectors.You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to select disparate elements. The order of the DOM elements in the returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in document order. An alternative to this combinator is the .add() method.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/